# Is there any way to make Go's channels behave like a stack

Tags: stack, queue, go, channel

Go channels by default behave like a queue as far as I can tell, first in first out. Is there any way to change them to work last in first out?

Basically I am doing a search and want to do DFS instead of BFS for memory constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible - channels are always FIFO. You could use package [`container/heap`](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/).

Comment: Confused since my code snippet seems to show that what is sent first is received last https://play.golang.org/p/SJ_dnzuDjsJ

Comment: The order in which your goroutines execute is non-deterministic. Try executing your code locally several times and observe the order. The Go playground caches results.

Comment: digging deeper I read that go has this lack of synchronization https://golang.org/ref/mem .. if needed they recommend "explicit synchronization"